# Brainfuck interpreter problems

Tags: c, interpreter, brainfuck

I'm new to C. Currently I'm trying to write a Brainfuck interpreter. I have tried this so far.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char    *line;
int     curr_pos;

void    interprete(char *coms)
{
    int a;
    int curr_loop;

    a = -1;
    curr_loop = 0;
    while (line[++a])
        line[a] = 0;
    a = -1;
    while (coms[++a])
    {
        if (coms[a] == '+')
            line[curr_pos]++;
        else if (coms[a] == '-')
            line[curr_pos]--;
        else if (coms[a] == '>')
            curr_pos++;
        else if (coms[a] == '<')
            curr_pos--;
        else if (coms[a] == '.')
            write(1, &line[curr_pos], 1);
        else if (coms[a] == '[')
        {
            if (line[curr_pos])
                curr_pos++;
            else
            {
                curr_loop = 1;
                while (curr_loop)
                {
                    ++a;
                    if (coms[a] == '[')
                        curr_loop++;
                    else if (coms[a] == ']')
                        curr_loop--;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (coms[a] == ']')
        {
            if (line[curr_pos])
            {
                curr_loop = 1;
                while (curr_loop)
                {
                    --a;
                    if (coms[a] == '[')
                        curr_loop--;
                    else if (coms[a] == ']')
                        curr_loop++;
                }
            }
            else
                curr_pos++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    if (ac == 2)
    {
        curr_pos = 0;
        line = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4096);
        interprete(av[1]);
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
}
```

It works only without loops ("[" and "]").When I try:

```
++++++++++[>+++++++>++++++++++>+++>+<<<<-]>++.>+.+++++++..+++.>++.<<+++++++++++++++.>.+++.------.--------.>+.>.
```

It gives me the output

```
^B^A^H^H^K^B^Q^K^N^H^@^C^@
```

Expected output:

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: What is your question? Also looking at your code, I think you should avoid if forest and use cases instead.

Comment: Why it gives the wrong output and how to make my code better (maybe).

Comment: @Mayerz You're right but this is a kind of a problem, task and I'm not allowed to use cases.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @Klas Lindbäck output: Hello World!

Comment: Your initialization of `line` seams strange to me, specially the end of loop: you write 0 inside line until you find first null element. But line is allocated with malloc, so, no guarantee to have at least one element to zero nor this kind of suite (1, 2, 0, 4)

Comment: So, how to correctly initialize it?

Comment: You can use [calloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_calloc.htm) or pass the size to the function and loop on this size instead of loop searching for null terminator. `line = calloc(4096, 1);`

Comment: And you must check `malloc & friends` returned value `!= NULL`.

Comment: @LPs it doesn't change anything, but still a good point

Comment: I was answering to your last question. If the code is not outputting what you expect, you should debug it....

Comment: @LPs I said maybe, so it's a less important question

Comment: please use { and }, if you have a block-relatet error in your code, it is very hard to detect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problems are in the following code-blocks:

```
else if (coms[a] == '[')
{
    ...
}
else if (coms[a] == ']')
{
    ...
}
```

The program is looking for the other bracket (and finds it), but your code-pointer is additionally incremented in your `while`-statement (line 17). So you have to decrement `a` by `1` after your search-loops. The second problem is, that you increment the *data*-pointer (`curr_pos`)
if `com[a] == '['` and `line[curr_pos] != 0`
and if `com[a] == ']'` and `line[curr_pos] == 0`
You have to increment the *code*-pointer (`a`) what is still automatically incremented in your `while`-statement. So actually you have to pass in this case. Finally, you actually don't have to check at *both* brackets if the current cells value is unequal to zero. My suggested code would look like this:

```
else if (coms[a] == '[')
{
    if (!line[curr_pos])
    {
        curr_loop = 1;
        while (curr_loop)
        {
            ++a;
            if (coms[a] == '[')
                cur_loop++;
            else if (coms[a] == ']')
                cur_loop--;
        }
        a--;
    }
}
else if (coms[a] == ']')
{
    // You can always jump back to the opening bracket '['
    // because then the program checks again and jumps behind
    // the closing bracket if line[a] != 0
    curr_loop = 1;
    while (curr_loop)
    {
        --a;
        if (coms[a] == '[')
            curr_loop--;
        else if (coms[a] == ']')
            curr_loop++;
    }
    a--;
}
```

By the way: try to implement the '`,`'-command. It makes brainfuck programs way more interesting ;)